# Find CMYK coverage in PDF with Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, color-space, cmyk

I'm working on a tool where the user could upload a PDF with an image and then receive information about area and CMYK colors from the image.

Initially I thought that RGB values would be enough, so I used PdfBox library(PDFRenderer class) to convert the PDF to an RGB image and then counted the colors for each pixel. This works, but now I need CMYK values. I've been spending some time trying to convert RGB values to CMYK values, but can't get good results. It's not accurate at all. I've never worked with color spaces before, so it's a struggle.

Is there a reliable way of loading a PDF document and reading its CMYK values? Is there maybe a reliable way of converting RGB to CMYK, that I missed?

```
// Load CMYK ICC file
InputStream is = TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("USWebCoatedSWOP.icc")

// Load PDF Document
PDDocument doc = PDDPDDocument.load(TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.pdf"))

// Render image from document
BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 600, ImageType.RGB);

// Read a pixel from image 
float[] rgbF = new float[3];
bufferedImage.getData().getPixel(0,0,rgbF);

// Load color spaces
ColorSpace cmykCS = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(is));

// Prepare RGB values for CMYK (I assume we want RGB values in [0.0, 1.0] ranger. I did try [0.0, 255.0] range as well. Was even worse).
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    rgbF[i] = rgbF[i] / 255.0f;
}

// Convert to CMYK
float[] cmyk = cmykCS.fromRGB(rgbF);
```

I also tried first converting to CIEXYZ, but same result:

```
ColorSpace rgbCS = ICC_ColorSpace.getInstance(ICC_ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
float[] cmyk = ascmykCS.fromCIEXYZ(rgbCS.toCIEXYZ(rgbF))
```

Comment: If the PDF is originally RGB then the only way to get 'reliable' CMYK coverage is to use exactly the same conversion as the final device. There's usually no way to know that. You don't say how you are currently converting RGB to CMYK, nor how you are verifying that it isn't accurate. I could point you at the PostScript quick-and-dirty method but that's rarely used nowadays. You can't just take a PDF file and 'read it's CMYK values' because the content of the PDF can be described in a bewildering variety of colour spaces. Ghostscript's inkcov device could help, maybe.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.

From what I've been told, the PDF is already in CMYK color space. If I check in Adobe Reader, the color spaces for both RGB and CMYK are both set.

RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
CMYK: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2

For conversion I used java.awt.color.ColorSpace. For RGB a default one, for CMYK I downloaded the appropriate ICC file. And then manually checked converted values in a web tool.

I'll add the conversion code, good point. And I'll check the Ghostscript stuff, thanks.